# How can I manage multiple threads in c with pthread?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, pthreads

I am trying to write a program that can scale to use a dynamic number of pthreads based on core count to parallelize a simple algorithm. The algorithm is simple it takes an integer array of inputs and if each location is %10 != 0 it stores 0 in the corresponding output array location, else it stores 10.  I don't think the problem is there as it is such a simple problem... but I don't understand why this doesn't work:

```
/*This variable is our reference to the child threads */
pthread_t childThreads[threadCount];

/*
...other setup code to initialize the parameters...
*/


/* create child threads*/
for(int i = 0; i< threadCount; i++)
{
    printf("running_P...\n");
    if(pthread_create(&(childThreads[i]), NULL, runParallelAlgorithm, (void *) &(parallelDataPakages[i])))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error creating thread\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
/* join child threads*/
for(int i = 0; i< threadCount; i++)
{
    if(pthread_join(childThreads[i], NULL))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error joining thread\n");
        return 2;
    }
    printf("not_running_P...\n");
}
```

and the output from this is:

```
running_P...
running_P...
running_P...
running_P...
not_running_P...
Error joining thread

Process returned 2 (0x2)   execution time : 0.047 s
Press any key to continue.
```

I have tried looking at other solutions, but it looks like most people are trying to use the same pthread_t variable to make threads, whereas I have an array... but it still seems to fail to join?  Why?  I tried to cut it down to only the relevant code, but because I can provide more information if necessary.

Edit: Sorry I didn't provide enough information.  The actual program is nearly 200 lines and I didn't really want to post it all here initially.  But if the issue isn't in this section I'm not sure what it causing this issue.  Seeing as this isn't the issue though, I will link a gist with the code included.  The actual join that is causing issues is on line 140, sorry I can't really figure out what else it would be specifically: https://gist.github.com/firestar9114/d77b72254d4ef93664fbda14a9ed1a19

Update: The `pthread_join()` function returns an int equal to `ESRCH` which is listed as "No thread with the ID *thread* could be found." in the manual.  I am using the same array of `childThreads[]` to create and to join the threads, and I am using the same control variable of `threadCount` which is always 4, so I don't understand why the thread id can't be found?  I tried adding a `pthread_exit(NULL);` statement, but it still doesn't seem to work...  Any ideas given this new information???

Comment: It's best to post minimal, but complete example that exhibits unexpected behavior.

Comment: Using an array of `pthread_t` is perfectly fine, and you seem to be doing it correctly.  Please present a [mcve] -- that's our usual standard for debugging questions such as this one.  I think that will clarify that the problem is in some part of your code other than the fragments you've presented so far.

Comment: I added a link to the test code I am working with.  If you can point out the specific issue, I can update my question to include it.

Comment: you could at least check the return error code of `pthread_join` to see why it is failing, that might offer some hints. The [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_join) lists the possible error codes.

Comment: What is erno and how do I check it?  Edit: nvm, I will try to figure that out, and get back here later.  Thanks...

Comment: sorry I mispoke with errno,, fixed the comment now. Errno (short for error number) is a system error code that a lot of functions respect. A common paradigm is "on error, the function returns -1 and sets errno to the error code." giving you more info about _why_ the function failed. But in this case, `pthread_join` simply returns an error code, doesn't look like it writes to errno at all. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errno.h

Comment: Finally got back and had a chance to test it out, the error is "ESRCH" - No thread with the ID thread could be found... but it should be using the same threads that are used to create it???  It's the same array.

Comment: @Firestar9114, a MCVE *does not* mean posting your whole program.  It means posting the smallest complete program you can come up with the exhibits the same problem.  You can prepare such a thing either by cutting everything unnecessary out of your original or by writing a new, similar program from scratch.  Either way, be sure to confirm that the result exhibits the same problem.  Note, too, that it is not uncommon for the process of producing a MCVE to lead you to discover the source of the problem yourself.

Comment: In any case, no, a link to your program on an external site is not an acceptable substitute for an MCVE presented in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the problem at the completely wrong place.

The root cause is a buffer overrun, here:

```
        /*advance the element pointer*/
        inputPointer = inputPointer + (sizeof(int) * elementsToProcess[i]);
        outputPointer = outputPointer + (sizeof(int) * elementsToProcess[i]);
```

You want to advance `int *inputPointer` and `int *outputPointer` by `elementsToProcess[i]`. The multiplication by the size of an `int` is completely bogus: incrementing or decrementing a pointer changes the address by the size of the pointed to type, so that it points to the next or previous element if in an array. So, it should be

```
        inputPointer = inputPointer + elementsToProcess[i];
        outputPointer = outputPointer + elementsToProcess[i];
```

or better yet,

```
        inputPointer += elementsToProcess[i];
        outputPointer += elementsToProcess[i];
```

Essentially, your code is scribbling over other data, including `childThreads[]` and C library internal allocation metadata.

Comment: OH!  I see!  I had no clue that it automatically adjusted for the type, I thought it had to be something in pthreads, because when I removed the thread functions it worked.  Thanks for pointing that out!  I was still trying to go through line by line at this point trying to figure out why it wasn't working.  :)

Comment: Why does a buffer overflow stop the threads from joining though?  Do pthreads not exit when they hit an error, like an overflow?

Comment: @Firestar9114 overwriting a buffer is one of the many ways in C to invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). After you do such a thing, anything can happen moving forward, it's senseless to try to understand how the program behaves after that. In this case, the squashed memory after your buffer manifested with thread joining errors. If you recompile with different compiler flags you may get a segfault instead. If you run it on your buddy's machine it may appear to work just fine. Once you invoke UB, all bets are off.

Comment: @Firestar9114: What yano said; the failure mode does change by changing optimization level at compile time (`-O2`, `-Os`, or `-O0`) or architecture (x86, x86-64, ARM, so on), so knowing *"oops, `outputPointer` ends up pointing at wrong stuff, scribbling all over my global variables"* should be enough. It is not worth the effort trying to second-guess anything further, because there is nothing to learn there.